# I want to make random object fall faster after a given time

Tags: object, random, lua, coronasdk

How do i make random objects fall faster after the player has scored 300 points in corona sdk im using physics to make these objects fall
Can anyone please show me the code

Comment: How can anyone show you any code if you yourself don't show the code that's giving you trouble? :)

In general, to make sure people will help you, try [posting a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what stopps you from increasing gravity? https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/physics/setGravity.html

Comment: You may also increase velocity of objects.

Comment: I want to increase the grivity after a  certain point

Answer (score 0):

Corona provides a runtime event called EnterFrame that runs every frame.  You can use that runtime event to check against some condition (ex. reached a certain level or time) and if that condition is met, increase gravity.

```
local myListener = function( event )
    if condition then 
        local gx, gy = physics.getGravity()
        physics.SetGravity(gx, gy +10)
    end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", myListener )
```